# Selenium: XPath invalid for Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

i've tried this XPath to find values in a table with the Selenium WebDriver :

```
//*[contains(@id, 'tccell') and (contains(@id, '_2'))]//.[contains(text(),'some value')]
```

I've tested it in FirePath and it worked fine. However the WebDriver throws an exception saying it is an invalid XPath.
Anyone knows why?

Thanks.

Comment: Also throws exception in xpathtester.com : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/113de8b5489b2c233c0a5a9d493ff1d0

Comment: It is hard to suggest an alternative without knowing what you're trying to achieve, and how the target element looks like exactly...

Comment: How about this one : `//*[contains(@id, 'tccell') and contains(@id, '_2') and contains(.,'some value')]` ?

Comment: You have used `//.` try using `//*` instead for second tag

Comment: @har07 Your suggestion worked! Thanks :) Now that i think about it i could have came across that myself ^^

Comment: //*[contains(@id, 'tccell') and (contains(@id, '_2'))]//*[contains(text(),'some value')]

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
//*[contains(@id, 'tccell') and (contains(@id, '_2'))]//*[contains(text(),'some value')]
```